# Проблема с resize

Tags: изображения, imagemagick

Есть проблема. Я хотел бы знать, почему resize ведет себя так странно.
Я хочу преобразовать кучу файлов в определенный размер 10x7.

Я пишу так:

`magick mogrify -path D:\Users\User\Documents\small -resize 10x7 D:\Users\User\Documents\normal\*.tga`

Но получаю на выходе изображения размера 10х6, почему так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это нормально. Magick  сохраняет соотношение сторон. Если необходимо точные размеры, то используйте так:

```
magick mogrify -path D:\Users\User\Documents\small -resize 10x7! D:\Users\User\Documents\normal\*.tga
```

см.: https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/

Comment: Лучше использовать -thumbnail, эта опция как раз для создания миниатюр предназначена.